# Migrating dispatch_group_leave() to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, api, migration, dispatch

I'm trying to migrate the code below to Swift 3.

```
func fetchTemplatesForField(_ fieldId: Int, entryGroupId: Int? = 0, templateFieldResponseDelegate: TemplateFieldResponseDelegate) -> Void {

    // Dispatch group will maintain the entry and exit of templates api calls.
    self.templateFieldGroup = DispatchGroup()

    self.templateFieldGroup.enter()

    let fetchFieldGroupEndpoint = "\(serviceUrl!)/Actionables/GetTemplatesForField?fieldID=\(fieldId)"

    self.progressDataManager.incrementMaxValue(2)

    print("endpoint: \(fetchFieldGroupEndpoint)")

    AlamofireAPIManager.sharedManager.request(fetchFieldGroupEndpoint)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    print("fetchTemplatesForField: Success")

                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let responseJson = JSON(value)

                        self.fieldDataManager.saveTemplateFields(responseJson)

                        self.progressDataManager.incrementCurrentValue(2)

                        // self.templateFieldGroup.leave()
                   ===> dispatch_group_leave(self.templateFieldGroup)

                        return
                    }

                    self.templateFieldGroup.leave()
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("fetchTemplatesForField: error - \(error)")

                self.progressDataManager.incrementCurrentValue(2)

                self.templateFieldGroup.leave()

                return
            }
    }

    templateFieldGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        templateFieldResponseDelegate.onTemplateFieldSyncComplete(true)
            self.templateFieldGroup = DispatchGroup()
    }
}
```

When I convert to latest syntax, Swift wants to change the line `dispatch_group_leave(self.templateFieldGroup)` to `self.templateFieldGroup.leave()`.

Unfortunately, this crashes at runtime in Swift 3. The original code works fine in Swift 2.2. I'm not exactly sure what this is attempting to do, so am at a bit of a loss. Can anyone shed some light on it?

Edit:
What I find really confusing is the definition of DispatchGroup.

```
open class DispatchGroup : DispatchObject {
}

extension DispatchGroup {
    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public func enter()

    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public func leave()
}
```

How can I determine what these methods are actually supposed to do?

Comment: What's the error message from the crash?

Comment: Why are you using `self.templateFieldGroup`? It looks like you're creating a new instance of `DispatchGroup` inside this `fetchTemplatesForField` method. If you also have a `templateFieldGroup` property for your class it might be because you are mistaking the two. It looks like you call `templateFieldGroup.enter()` on the one within `fetchTemplatesForField`, so I would assume you'd want to call `leave()` on that as well, not the `self.templateFieldGroup` one.

Comment: @Pierce, they're actually the same. templateFieldGroup is declared at the class level. It's just instantiated in the function. I have edited the code above to include `self.` in all the calls. The one inside the api call requires the `self.` prefix -- `Reference to property 'templateFieldGroup' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit`.

Comment: @Code Different, the error message is: `Thread 19: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subside= 0x0)`. The following is in the console when it crashes: `fetchTemplatesForField: Success
warning: Swift error in module SwiftyJSON.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.`

Comment: I added the class definition to my question above. I'm not sure what it's actually supposed to do. This is code a different developer wrote. He is no longer available, and I'm trying to migrate the code and clean it up.